# jQuery .prop() : if Checked = (check all) else (uncheck all)

Tags: jquery

I've encountered a little problem when trying to create a "check all"-box.

It works, the first time. When doing it multiple times (like on, off and on again) then it doesn't check the boxes anymore!

HTML

```
<label><input type='checkbox' id='CheckAll' />Click me!</label><br />
<br />
<input type='checkbox' name='Checks' value='1' /><br />
<input type='checkbox' name='Checks' value='2' /><br />
<input type='checkbox' name='Checks' value='3' /><br />
<input type='checkbox' name='Checks' value='4' /><br />
<input type='checkbox' name='Checks' value='5' />
```

jQuery

```
$('#CheckAll').change(function() { 
    var $Checked = $(this).prop('checked'); 
    if ($Checked === true) { 
        $(document).find('input:checkbox[name=\'Checks\']').prop('checked', true); 
    } else { 
        $(document).find('input:checkbox[name=\'Checks\']').removeProp('checked'); 
    } 
});
```

I've reproduced the problem in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aTW8Y/1/

Am I overlooking something or trying to use the `.prop()` property the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.prop("checked", false);` instead of `removeProp`:

```
$('#CheckAll').change(function() { 
    $(document).find('input:checkbox[name=\'Checks\']')
               .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')); 
});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/):

> jQuery first assigns the value undefined to the property and ignores
>   any error the browser generates. In general, **it is only necessary to
>   remove custom properties that have been set on an object, and not
>   built-in (native) properties**

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezEWU/)

Comment: This answer was accepted because of the simplified function! Everyone got a upvote.. Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're removing the `checked` property, you should just set it to `false` instead:

```
$(document).find('input:checkbox[name=\'Checks\']').prop('checked', false);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTW8Y/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As the [`removeProp()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) states:

> **Note:** Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

In calling `removeProp()` you're completely removing the `checked` property from the checkboxes. Instead of that, simply use `prop()` to set the value to `false`:

```
$(document).find('input:checkbox[name=\'Checks\']').prop('checked', false);
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/aTW8Y/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use `prop('checked', false)` to remove the check, and secondly you can simplify your logic into a 1 liner:

```
$('#CheckAll').change(function() { 
    $('input:checkbox[name=\'Checks\']').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTW8Y/4/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/aTW8Y/5/

use `prop('checked', false)` instead!